# Chrony 3.1 refuses to sync with ntp server

Tags: centos, synchronization, troubleshooting, ntpd, chrony

I have 70 machine with CentOS 7.2 and chrony version 2.1.1 syncing perfect with my NTP server protocol v3.

**Recently I added 30 machines with** `CentOS 7.4 and chrony version 3.1`, but these 30 machines refuse to sync, I followed all the troubleshooting procedures and I am totally stuck figuring out how to fix that. commands output:

```
chronyc tracking
Reference ID    : 00000000 ()
Stratum         : 0
Ref time (UTC)  : Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 1970
System time     : 0.000000013 seconds fast of NTP time
Last offset     : +0.000000000 seconds
RMS offset      : 0.000000000 seconds
Frequency       : 11.390 ppm fast
Residual freq   : +0.000 ppm
Skew            : 0.000 ppm
Root delay      : 1.000000000 seconds
Root dispersion : 1.000000000 seconds
Update interval : 0.0 seconds
Leap status     : Not synchronised


chronyc sources
210 Number of sources = 1
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample
===============================================================================
^? 172.17.172.220                4   7   377   644   -11.6s[ -11.6s] +/- 8147ms



tcpdump -n -i lo port 323 [Note: I applied "chronyc sources" in other terminal but nothing captured, in the working machines it capture some packets!]

tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
^C
0 packets captured
0 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel


 tcpdump -n -i eno2  port 123
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eno2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
15:03:09.870958 IP 192.168.0.100.44841 > 172.17.172.220.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 48
15:03:10.112707 IP 172.17.172.220.ntp > 192.168.0.100.44841: NTPv3, Server, length 48
15:11:45.678320 IP 192.168.0.100.46832 > 172.17.172.220.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 48
15:11:45.892482 IP 172.17.172.220.ntp > 192.168.0.100.46832: NTPv3, Server, length 48
15:20:22.634981 IP 192.168.0.100.41310 > 172.17.172.220.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 48
15:20:22.871226 IP 172.17.172.220.ntp > 192.168.0.100.41310: NTPv3, Server, length 48
15:28:55.820943 IP 192.168.0.100.39143 > 172.17.172.220.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 48
15:28:55.873988 IP 172.17.172.220.ntp > 192.168.0.100.39143: NTPv3, Server, length 48
15:37:35.840998 IP 192.168.0.100.57333 > 172.17.172.220.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 48
15:37:35.913139 IP 172.17.172.220.ntp > 192.168.0.100.57333: NTPv3, Server, length 48
15:46:15.814980 IP 192.168.0.100.56932 > 172.17.172.220.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 48
15:46:15.882518 IP 172.17.172.220.ntp > 192.168.0.100.56932: NTPv3, Server, length 48
15:54:48.587705 IP 192.168.0.100.33711 > 172.17.172.220.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 48
15:54:48.632963 IP 172.17.172.220.ntp > 192.168.0.100.33711: NTPv3, Server, length 48
^C
14 packets captured
14 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel

chronyc activity
200 OK
1 sources online
0 sources offline
0 sources doing burst (return to online)
0 sources doing burst (return to offline)
0 sources with unknown address


chronyc ntpdata  172.17.172.220
Remote address  : 172.17.172.220 (AC11ACDC)
Remote port     : 123
Local address   : 192.168.0.100 (C0A80064)
Leap status     : Normal
Version         : 3
Mode            : Server
Stratum         : 4
Poll interval   : 8 (256 seconds)
Precision       : -6 (0.015625000 seconds)
Root delay      : 0.031219 seconds
Root dispersion : 8.063156 seconds
Reference ID    : AC11AC88 ()
Reference time  : Sun Nov 12 09:21:36 2017
Offset          : +11.719727516 seconds
Peer delay      : 0.215471357 seconds
Peer dispersion : 0.015626255 seconds
Response time   : 0.000000000 seconds
Jitter asymmetry: -0.47
NTP tests       : 111 111 1101
Interleaved     : No
Authenticated   : No
TX timestamping : Kernel
RX timestamping : Kernel
Total TX        : 35
Total RX        : 35
Total valid RX  : 35


chronyc serverstats
NTP packets received       : 0
NTP packets dropped        : 0
Command packets received   : 6
Command packets dropped    : 0
Client log records dropped : 0
```

**What should I do to fix**:

> Reference ID    : 00000000 ()
> Stratum         : 0
> NTP packets received       : 0

I already rebooted whole OS, tried all chronyc commands like makestep and waitsync. but nothing working. I also tried to find reported bugs but couldn't find any related.

note that firewalld disabled. and /etc/chrony.conf is exact copy from the working 70 machines.

**Update:**
By activating tcpdump's verbose mode, it seems chrony 3.1 timestamps corrupted, even by trying `chronyc makestep 1 -1` it didn't sync, also I ran debug mode "see below":

```
tcpdump -n -i eno2  port 123 -vvvvv
tcpdump: listening on eno2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
20:25:15.708374 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 399, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 76)
    192.168.0.100.49105 > 172.17.172.220.ntp: [bad udp cksum 0x1a45 -> 0xf15f!] NTPv4, length 48
        Client, Leap indicator:  (0), Stratum 0 (unspecified), poll 6 (64s), precision 32
        Root Delay: 0.000000, Root dispersion: 0.000000, Reference-ID: (unspec)
          Reference Timestamp:  0.000000000
          Originator Timestamp: 3719492661.028820399 (2017/11/12 20:24:21)
          Receive Timestamp:    1089474065.361510029 (2070/08/17 02:09:21)
          Transmit Timestamp:   2540453432.493019109 (1980/07/03 13:30:32)
            Originator - Receive Timestamp:  +1664948700.332689629
            Originator - Transmit Timestamp: -1179039228.535801290
20:25:15.964038 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 122, id 18400, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 76)
    172.17.172.220.ntp > 192.168.0.100.49105: [udp sum ok] NTPv3, length 48
        Server, Leap indicator:  (0), Stratum 4 (secondary reference), poll 6 (64s), precision -6
        Root Delay: 0.031219, Root dispersion: 8.154785, Reference-ID: 172.17.172.136
          Reference Timestamp:  3719467375.940868199 (2017/11/12 13:22:55)
          Originator Timestamp: 2540453432.493019109 (1980/07/03 13:30:32)
          Receive Timestamp:    3719492726.471868199 (2017/11/12 20:25:26)
          Transmit Timestamp:   3719492726.471868199 (2017/11/12 20:25:26)
            Originator - Receive Timestamp:  +1179039293.978849090
            Originator - Transmit Timestamp: +1179039293.978849090
```

Debug mode output:

```
/usr/sbin/chronyd -d -d
2017-11-12T17:32:37Z main.c:473:(main) chronyd version 3.1 starting (+CMDMON +NTP +REFCLOCK +RTC +PRIVDROP +SCFILTER +SECHASH +SIGND +ASYNCDNS +IPV6 +DEBUG)
2017-11-12T17:32:37Z conf.c:406:(CNF_ReadFile) Reading /etc/chrony.conf
2017-11-12T17:32:37Z conf.c:572:(CNF_ParseLine) commandkey directive is no longer supported
2017-11-12T17:32:37Z conf.c:572:(CNF_ParseLine) generatecommandkey directive is no longer supported
2017-11-12T17:32:37Z local.c:149:(calculate_sys_precision) Clock precision 0.000000016 (-26)
2017-11-12T17:32:37Z sys_linux.c:317:(get_version_specific_details) Linux kernel major=3 minor=10 patch=0
2017-11-12T17:32:37Z sys_linux.c:338:(get_version_specific_details) hz=100 nominal_tick=10000 max_tick_bias=1000
2017-11-12T17:32:37Z local.c:663:(lcl_RegisterSystemDrivers) Local freq=11.390ppm
2017-11-12T17:32:37Z util.c:1172:(UTI_DropRoot) Dropped root privileges: UID 998 GID 996
2017-11-12T17:32:37Z reference.c:209:(REF_Initialise) Frequency 11.390 +/- 0.031 ppm read from /var/lib/chrony/drift
2017-11-12T17:32:37Z sys_generic.c:251:(update_slew) slew offset=0.000000e+00 corr_rate=0.000000e+00 base_freq=11.389873 total_freq=11.389862 slew_freq=-1.093958e-11 duration=10000.000000 slew_error=1.203354e-13
2017-11-12T17:32:37Z ntp_core.c:1089:(transmit_timeout) Transmit timeout for [172.17.172.220:123]
2017-11-12T17:32:37Z ntp_io.c:831:(NIO_SendPacket) Sent 48 bytes to 172.17.172.220:123 from [UNSPEC] fd 8
2017-11-12T17:32:37Z ntp_io_linux.c:652:(NIO_Linux_ProcessMessage) Received 90 (48) bytes from error queue for 172.17.172.220:123 fd=8 if=3 tss=1
2017-11-12T17:32:37Z ntp_core.c:1994:(update_tx_timestamp) Updated TX timestamp delay=0.000010086
2017-11-12T17:32:38Z ntp_io.c:669:(process_message) Received 48 bytes from 172.17.172.220:123 to 192.168.0.100 fd=8 if=3 tss=1 delay=0.000014398
2017-11-12T17:32:38Z ntp_core.c:1563:(receive_packet) NTP packet lvm=34 stratum=4 poll=6 prec=-6 root_delay=0.031219 root_disp=8.201569 refid=ac11ac88 []
2017-11-12T17:32:38Z ntp_core.c:1568:(receive_packet) reference=1510478575.936134800 origin=3724568162.405584875 receive=1510507968.499134800 transmit=1510507968.499134800
2017-11-12T17:32:38Z ntp_core.c:1570:(receive_packet) offset=10.547374307 delay=0.099570973 dispersion=0.015824 root_delay=0.130790 root_dispersion=8.217393
2017-11-12T17:32:38Z ntp_core.c:1573:(receive_packet) remote_interval=0.000000000 local_interval=0.099570973 server_interval=0.000000000 txs=K rxs=K
2017-11-12T17:32:38Z ntp_core.c:1577:(receive_packet) test123=111 test567=111 testABCD=1111 kod_rate=0 interleaved=0 presend=0 valid=1 good=1 updated=1
2017-11-12T17:32:38Z sources.c:353:(SRC_AccumulateSample) ip=[172.17.172.220] t=1510507957.951760493 ofs=-10.547374 del=0.130790 disp=8.217393 str=4
2017-11-12T17:32:38Z sourcestats.c:658:(SST_GetSelectionData) n=1 off=-10.547374 dist=8.282888 sd=4.000000 first_ago=0.049800 last_ago=0.049800 selok=0
2017-11-12T17:32:38Z sources.c:770:(SRC_SelectSource) badstat=1 sel=0 badstat_reach=1 sel_reach=0 max_reach_ago=0.000000
```

**Confirming that the issue within ver 3.1:**

By removing 3.1 `yum remove chrony` and reverting back to chronyd version 2.1.1 `yum localinstall /home/chrony-2.1.1-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm`, Sync worked perfect!

Comment: You can try Chrony 3.2 . Maybe this issue has been resolved in later version. CentOS repo has `3.1` as latest. https://git.tuxfamily.org/chrony/chrony.git/refs/

Comment: You can take `rpm` version of `Chrony 3.2` from fedora repo. https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/chrony

Answer (score 11):

There is a similar bug in RH Bugzilla that was closed as notabug. The issue is a combination of poor time server and a change in defaults for newer chrony to not use them.

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1525833

"The server is ignored for synchronization of the clock because it's too inaccurate. In the "chronyc sources" output there is "+/- 4695ms", which is larger than the default maxdistance of 3 seconds. The maxdistance option was added in chrony-2.2, so that's why it worked with chrony-2.1. Older versions only have a hardcoded limit for the root dispersion to be smaller than 16 seconds.

The tcpdump output shows that the NTP server has a root dispersion of about 3.6 seconds. Is it a Windows NTP server? You can also check the root dispersion with "chronyc ntpdata".

A larger maxdistance needs to be set in chrony.conf to allow chronyd to use the server for synchronization."

Comment: yes, its windows NTP server.

Comment: I had servers that were almost a full day offset and wouldn't sync. Updating `maxdistance` solved this for me, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

### For chrony 3.1.

We've pieced together a solution based on the following thread, but for a concise, simple to check answer try the following. Check the status of the time sync you receive with following command (-v explains the columns)

```
chronyc sources -v
```

The far right column (e.g. +/- 10.5s) tells you the 'estimated error' of the time update received from the server in question.

Our issue was that the time received from windows NTP server exceeded the 'max estimated error' threshold of 3 seconds (they were +/- 10 seconds) and therefore chrony was not updating system time accordingly. Setting our servers to use UK NTP pool servers corrected the issue (+/- 50 ms)

Answer (score 3):

If you have a windows based NTP server, maybe this will be a fix for you (It worked for me in a similar problem):

https://chrony.tuxfamily.org/faq.html

> 3.4. Using a Windows NTP server? A common issue with Windows NTP servers is that they report a very large root dispersion (e.g. three
> seconds or more), which causes chronyd to ignore the server for being
> too inaccurate. The sources command might show a valid measurement,
> but the server is not selected for synchronisation. You can check the
> root dispersion of the server with the chronyc's ntpdata command.
>
> The maxdistance value needs to be increased in chrony.conf to enable
> synchronisation to such a server. For example:
>
> maxdistance 16.0